# spark: WARN amfilter.AmIpFilter: Could not find proxy-user cookie, so user will not be set

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Do you know why this error below happens in spark shell when I try to access spark UI master:4040?

```
 WARN amfilter.AmIpFilter: Could not find proxy-user cookie, so user will not be set
```

Comment: Googled it and found this - https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201502.mbox/%3CCAHUQ+_bAtgGe9JFu2rKVmsadp5Z9OOHJu6X1Ov=op+uoPtXwZA@mail.gmail.com%3E.

Answer (score 4):

This happens, if you start spark shell with yarn.

```
spark-shell --master yarn
```

In that case, YARN will start a proxy web application to increase the security of the overall system.
The URL of the proxy will be displayed in the log, while starting the Spark shell.
Here is a sample from my log:

```
16/06/26 08:38:28 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> myhostname, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://myhostname:8088/proxy/application_1466917030969_0003), /proxy/application_1466917030969_0003
```

You shouldn't access the standard Spark Web UI using port 4040 (or whatever you have configured).
Instead I know these 2 options (where I prefere the 2nd one):

1. Scan the log for the proxy application URL and use that
2. Open the YARN Web UI http://localhost:8088/cluster and
   follow the link to the ApplicationMaster (column Tracking UI) of the
   running Spark application

This is also descibed briefly in the YARN and SPark documentation.

Spark Security documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html

Yarn Web Application Proxy documentation:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebApplicationProxy.html